# elasticsearch convert unixtime to datetime format

Tags: elasticsearch, unix-timestamp, datetime-format

I would like to know how to convert a unixtime field to date/time into an elasticsearch query.

below an example of  my script:

```
  {
     "fields" : [
        "alert.dateActivated",
        "alert.systemName", 
        "alert.caption",
    ],
   "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {"match_all": {}},
            "filter": { 
                "and": [
                    {"term": {"type": "10"}},
                    {"range": {"@timestamp": {"gte": "2016-01-01","lte": "2016-05-25"}}}
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below is an output example of this query:

```
1461791393727   "UCA-AGU-AA-BR-W17-01"  "Alarma Refrigerante AA#2"
1461791357142   "ICA-ICA-AA-BR-W60-01"  "Alarma Refrigerante AA#2"
1461791642125   "LIM-SVC-AA-BR-W17-01"  "Alarma Refrigerante AA#2"
1461791447285   "ICA-ICA-AA-BR-W60-01"  "Falla Energia AA#1"
1461792049657   "LIM-SVC-AA-BR-W17-01"  "Falla Energia AA#2"
```

The goal is convert the first column (unixtime format) to date/time format.

NOTE:  if possible, not using groovy script execution, because I'm getting performance issues using script execution due the amount of data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have the possibility of changing that format before indexing the document into ES?

Comment: Hi @Val  ...  No, this is part of a big solution and I cannot make changes on indexes because are being used in other many applications.

Comment: And can't your client code handle this formatting need?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Val   ...  I'm using Domo Centerview to display this data from Elastic, Domo is limited handling data, there is not an option to convert unixt to datetime format.  For this reason I'm trying to transform the data from source.